# Halley's method

Tags: numerical-methods, maple

Halley's method uses a quadratic Taylor approximation and results in a fixed point method of order $3$:

> $$
> x_{n + 1}
> =
> x_{n}
> -
> {{\rm f}\left(x_{n}\right) \over {\rm f}'\left(x_{n}\right)}\,
> \left[%
> 1
> -
> {{\rm f}\left(x_{n}\right){\rm f}''\left(x_{n}\right)
>  \over
>  2{\rm f}'^{2}\left(x_{n}\right)} \right]^{-1}
> $$

My original question about finding the cube root of 5 using Halley's method has been solved.

How do I verify numerically that the convergence is cubic?

I know that I have to use the order of convergence formula, but how do I set it up on Maple?

Comment: Just look for a root of $f(x)=x^3-5$ using this method (I hope you are able to differentiate this function twice). WTF would Hermite polynomials do here?

Comment: @arbautjc How did you find the function? I don't think I actually understand the question. Is it similar to finding a root of a function?

Comment: Do you know what a [cube root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_root) is? By the way, yes, [Halley's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halley%27s_method) is just about finding the root of a function! It's just an improvement on [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)

Comment: I know what cube root and Newton's method are. But I don't understand how to apply the function. Do I just use it in Newton's method?

Comment: No. A cube root of $A$ is a number $x$ that satisfies $x^3=A$, or $x^3-A=0$ You put your function ($x\to x^3-5$) in the formula above, like you would do with Newton's method. Then you choose a starting point, as you would do with Newton's method. And you compute successive point with this formula, as you would do with Newton's method. Really, what is the problem?

Comment: In Maple, there's a built-in command for Newton's method, but for this I think I have to write some commands on my own that's all.

Comment: Basically, yes, you have to do something. Here the problem should not be mathematics, but coding: if you know how to write a function in Maple, how to write a loop, and how to differentiate a function, there is not much difficulty. I could help you with Maxima, but not with Maple (it's been too long since I last used it: more than 10 years)

Comment: Yes, I have solved the problem thanks man. Can I ask u another question related to this if u don't mind? Now I want to verify that the convergence is cubic. I can write the codes but need to mathematically understand it.

Comment: You could plot $\frac{|x_{n+1} - \xi|}{|x_n- \xi|^3}$ as a function of $n$.

Comment: well, im trying to use fixed point iteration to show that it converges to sqrt(3) actually.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11918/discussion-between-ajr-and-arbautjc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can estimate the order of the convergence numerically. The procedure `estimateorder` below is just one of several ways to do it.

First, `H` is a short and workable (but inefficient) implementation of the method, with no stopping criteria other then a maximal number of iterations. Note that this procedure stores and returns all the iterates, not just the final one. Presumably you already have your own implementation.

```
restart:

H:=proc(expr,x,x0,maxiter)
  local ddf, df, f, n, X;
  f:=unapply(expr,x);
  df:=D(f);
  ddf:=(D@@2)(f);
  X:=Vector[':-row'](maxiter,[x0]);
  for n from 1 to maxiter-1 do
    X[n+1]:=evalf(X[n]-f(X[n])/df(X[n])/(1-(f(X[n])*ddf(X[n]))/(2*df(X[n])^2)));
  end do;
  X;
end proc:
```

Let's run that on an example, and make sure to have lots of digits in the results, for comparing.

```
Digits := 100:
V := H( x^3-5, x, 37.0, 10 ):
```

Here's the last term in that result,

```
V[10];

        1.709975946676696989353108872543860109868055110543054924382861707444295920504\

           173216257187010020189002
```

Now a procedure which estimates the order of convergence.

```
estimateorder:=proc(S::Vector)
  local d1, d2, dim, i, k, n1, n2, P;
  dim := op(1,S);
  P := Vector[row](dim-3);
  k := dim-3;
  for i from 1 to dim-3 do
     d1, d2 := S[i+2]-S[i+1], S[i+1]-S[i];
     if d1=0.0 or d2=0.0 then
        P[i]:=FAIL; k:=i-1; i:=dim-3; next;
     end if;
     n1, n2 := S[i+3]-S[i+2], S[i+2]-S[i+1];
     P[i] := ln(abs(n1/d1))/ln(abs(n2/d2));
     if not type(P[i],numeric) then
        P[i]:=FAIL; k:=i-1; i:=dim-3; next;
     end if;
     P[i] := evalf[5](P[i]);
  end do;
  P[1..k];
end proc:

estimateorder(V);

          [1.0089, 1.0692, 1.4427, 2.3523, 2.8416, 2.9932, 3.0000]
```

Notice that the convergence rate may be much worse initially, and that it only tends to cubic.

Another example, for illustration

```
Digits := 100:
ee:=randpoly(x,degree=7,dense);

             7       6       5       4       3       2     
         -7 x  + 22 x  - 55 x  - 94 x  + 87 x  - 56 x  - 62

V:=H( ee, x, 37.0, 30 ):

V[20]; # the final term

   -1.6254993522230776878001145071381988387744828918946894060940899\

      42338528314967927805393172797627178796

eval(ee,x=%): evalf[5](%); # is it close to being a root?

                                 -71
                        9.7076 10   

convert( estimateorder(V), list);

    [0.99752, 0.99468, 0.98841, 0.97453, 0.94513, 0.89261, 0.85937, 

     1.0931, 1.2070, -2.0048, -2.8923, -1.2156, -0.85385, 0.95828, 

     2.7835, 2.9570, 2.9997, 3.0000]

estimateorder(V)[-1];

                          3.0000
```